# There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later - Paypal

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal, paypal-express, exception

I've been getting this random error that occurs when customers try to checkout using PayPal Express

```
There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later
```

I've looked in the exception.log file but I am not sure what could be causing it as it is completely random.

```
2014-05-20T11:03:18+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.' in /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(987): Mage::throwException('There was an er...')
#1 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(655): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('DoDirectPayment', Array)
#2 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Direct.php(343): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callDoDirectPayment()
#3 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Direct.php(178): Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct->_placeOrder(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), 30)
#4 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(1077): Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct->authorize(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), 30)
#5 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(342): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_authorize(true, 30)
#6 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(885): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#7 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1103): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#8 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#9 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#10 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#11 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#12 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#13 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(785): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#14 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#15 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#16 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#17 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
2014-05-20T11:44:16+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP CURL connection error #28: Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received' in /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:972
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(655): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('DoDirectPayment', Array)
#1 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Direct.php(343): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callDoDirectPayment()
#2 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Direct.php(178): Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct->_placeOrder(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), 55)
#3 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(1077): Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct->authorize(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), 55)
#4 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(342): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_authorize(true, 55)
#5 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(885): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#6 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1103): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#7 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#8 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#9 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#10 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#11 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#12 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(785): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#13 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#14 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#15 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#16 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
2014-05-20T11:44:16+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Unable to communicate with the PayPal gateway.' in /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(977): Mage::throwException('Unable to commu...')
#1 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(655): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('DoDirectPayment', Array)
#2 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Direct.php(343): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callDoDirectPayment()
#3 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Direct.php(178): Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct->_placeOrder(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), 55)
#4 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(1077): Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct->authorize(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), 55)
#5 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(342): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_authorize(true, 55)
#6 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(885): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#7 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1103): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#8 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#9 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#10 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#11 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#12 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#13 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(785): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#14 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#15 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#16 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#17 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /chroot/home/mysite/mysitean.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
```

Has anyone come accross this issue and successfully diagnosed it before? I'd appreciate if you could assist me...

Comment: contact them as the error mentioned so.. btw, what is your currency? because paypal doesn't support some currencies.

Comment: @Mr_Green We are using GBP how do I contact technical support?

Answer (score 9):

I would say this is your error:

> PayPal NVP CURL connection error #28: Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

And I would interpret as PayPal is not reachable. Maybe they were down? Or is this an repeating error? Try to fire a request to the API if something comes back everything is fine, if not, maybe your admin blocks *.paypal.com!?

Whatever it is, the request magento sends to paypal is ignored and runs into a timeout.

Comment: It happens sporadically but some orders are able to get through and complete while other are getting the exception...

Comment: I have only one idea: Log _ALL_ requests and then retry. The problem is, that I'm sure you can't replay paypal requests - hopefully you can't :D

Comment: I checked the logs and it appears we are definitely connecting to paypal and making requests from the DoDirectPayment method. I sent the log to PayPal and they confirmed the error code so it looks like the failed transaction could be from the card provider fraud prevention...

Comment: great response to an error... timeout. *facepalm*

Comment: I know, at least they replied sheesh!

Answer (score 3):

As a follow on to Fabian's answer.  I have just been having the `PayPal NVP CURL connection error #28` problem on a dev site trying to do some testing on the Paypal Pro checkout after installing patches.

Using [this answer here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43259/paypal-sandbox-error-10001-timeout-processing-request#answer-43713) it turns out my problem was actually Paypal's own test card details they've published on their website.

As Paypal_Martin has pointed out;

> Do not use 5555555555554444 or 4111111111111111 - refer to
>   http://www.darkcoding.net/credit-card-numbers/ for a viable card
>   number generator

So nothing to do with upgrading and restarting server, reissuing SSL certs, disabling basic auth or all the other things that I tried.  Just bad card details.

Comment: really good advice. Trying different addresses (real or looking real) and CC numbers led to success order

Comment: McNab, you saved me hours of frustration. Only answer which worked.

Comment: Thanks @vladPavlov - I remember at the time thinking maybe I shouldn't post that as it wasn't technically an answer.  Really glad I did now, cheers!