# PayPal Sandbox: Error 10001: Timeout processing request

Tags: paypal, paypal-express, paypal-pro

I'm playing a few hours with this strange error.

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 & PayPal Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout).
I'm sure I have set all the creds correctly. Debug modes & Sandbox is turned on.

Neither Payments Pro nor Express Checkout is working.

What is in the `payment_paypal_direct.log`:

```
2014-11-09T12:13:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
  [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
  [DoDirectPayment] => Array
    (
        [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
        [IPADDRESS] => XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
        [RETURNFMFDETAILS] => 1
        [AMT] => 242.65
        [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
        [INVNUM] => 3025276
        [NOTIFYURL] => http://store.example.org/us/paypal/ipn/
        [EMAIL] => s******@gmail.com
        [CREDITCARDTYPE] => ****
        [ACCT] => ****
        [EXPDATE] => ****
        [CVV2] => ****
        [ISSUENUMBER] => 
        [ITEMAMT] => 235.00
        [TAXAMT] => 0.00
        [SHIPPINGAMT] => 7.65
        [L_NUMBER0] => D261
        [L_NAME0] => Product Name
        [L_QTY0] => 1
        [L_AMT0] => 235.00
        [BUSINESS] => 
        [FIRSTNAME] => Dr. Elizabeth A.
        [LASTNAME] => Asante
        [MIDDLENAME] => 
        [SALUTATION] => 
        [SUFFIX] => 
        [COUNTRYCODE] => US
        [STATE] => CA
        [CITY] => Fresno
        [STREET] => XXXX E Madison Ave
        [ZIP] => XXXXX
        [PHONENUM] => +1 XXX-XXX-XXXX
        [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
        [SHIPTOSTATE] => CA
        [SHIPTOCITY] => Fresno
        [SHIPTOSTREET] => XXXX E Madison Ave
        [SHIPTOZIP] => XXXXX
        [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => +1 XXX-XXX-XXXX
        [SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
        [STREET2] => 
        [SHIPTONAME] => Dr. Elizabeth A. Asante
        [METHOD] => DoDirectPayment
        [VERSION] => 72.0
        [USER] => ****
        [PWD] => ****
        [SIGNATURE] => ****
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
    )

  [response] => Array
    (
        [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-11-09T12:13:24Z
        [CORRELATIONID] => 6f2bd705b0a21
        [ACK] => Failure
        [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
        [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
        [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Timeout processing request
    )

  [__pid] => 2271
)
```

The similar is in the `payment_paypal_express.log`.

The `exception.log` file says that `Exception' with message 'PayPal response hasn't required fields.` and right after that `exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.'`.

The store currency is set properly.

php.ini's `arg_separator.output = "&amp;"`

In the PayPal Sandbox I have created a business account and a customer account. 
Business account's API is used in the Magento's backend (PayPal settings).

What else have I set up to make it working properly?

Actually I read about [this solution](http://www.submitdigital.com/questions/paypal-express-checkout-error/), but I don't know how to do that in the PayPal's Sandbox UI.

**Any answer would be appreciated!**

Comment: Ok, I've found that there is an issue of paypal credentials encoding. To check that, I debug `Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp` class'es `call` method. The problem is in `$request` variable — it holds incorrect broken PayPal API credentials (i.e. username is: `??>>?3x? ????ƿc1?????? 9>?(?Λv?`. The only problem to figure out why the correctly set API Creds converts to these weird stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error 10001 is an unhandled exception within the PayPal code.
Basically, there's no better error message available.

With that being said, on the sandbox there are three main issues causing error 10001:

1. Temporary issue: Some issue is causing connection problems between different server pools or the database and the payment code cannot recover from the connection problem.
2. An intermittent issue, which occurs every once in a while and doesn't seem to have a pattern. There's like some kind of performance issue on our side when the API Request is being processed - this is usually being caused by the data being sent. e.g. some Test Credit Card Numbers circulating on the internet will cause an error 10001 on every payment attempt.

   Do not use 5555555555554444 or 4111111111111111 - refer to http://www.darkcoding.net/credit-card-numbers/ for a viable card number generator
3. A permanent issue. If the PayPal Sandbox API always returns 10001 and you're not using a well known credit card number, feel free to contact http://www.paypal.com/mts and forward the correlationID that was contained in the API call (as well as the request itself)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but the problem was in incorrect credentials. I don't yet know why the creds are stored as unreadable and undecodeable properly format, I've hardcoded as a temp workaround..

Answer (score 1):

I checked if all credentials are correct. It's not working because of Magento latest patch release "SUPEE-8167".

Hopefully it will help someone who is working on same issue.